# Android Unit test Xml.newSerializer() always return null

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, android-espresso

I am trying to **unit test** in **Android** a class that uses `XmlSerializer` but for some reason, `Xml.newSerializer` always returns null. The app code that uses `xmlSerializer` runs fine though. Does anyone know why it only returns null when unit testing?

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer;

public class TestClass
{
    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
        if (serializer == null) {
            System.out.println("Is Null!");
        }
    }
}
```

The test frameworks I am using are Espresso and Mockito. Thanks.

Comment: Need more context of when it is returning null. provide a [mcve] that reproduces the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many classes that are provided in the Android platform. Unit tests are run against stubbed versions of these in a library on your computer. They are stubbed in that their methods will return `null`.

The problem seems to be the `Xml.newSerializer()` - the stubbed version of `Xml` will just return `null` from this method call.

One possible workaround is to run this unit test `androidTest` instead of in `test`. You will then have to run the unit test on the device rather than on your computer.

Another option is installing [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/). This provides working alternatives to the stubs that will allow you to execute unit tests without using the emulator.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I ended up doing. I used Robolectric.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory` which doesn't depend on Android platform

```
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
XmlSerializer serializer = factory.newSerializer();
```

just make sure you add `testImplementation 'net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0'` to the dependencies in build.gradle